# Announcing a Pro Tempore election

Tags: discussion, election

**Summary**: Joomla Stack Exchange will begin the nomination stage for [a special election](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/election/1) on **May 13** to bring in one more moderator.

For full details of the process, see [the announcement on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections). The timeline:

- Starting on May 13, users can [nominate themselves](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/election/1). Users can also ask questions on meta for potential moderators to answer. (Use the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) and [election](/questions/tagged/election) tags.)
- On May 20, if there are two or more candidates, we'll run an election. If not, I'll simply appoint the candidate. (There's a small chance we'll need to [remove a nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year), but I doubt that will come up.)
- If there is an election, I'll announce the results on meta on May 28.

(Note for current moderators: there's no need to nominate yourself even though you'll likely get an email saying you should. The system assumes the first election is a graduation election, which would mean moderators would need to be re-elected. This isn't that sort of election.)

If you have any questions about the process, please stick them in an answer here.

Comment: let's say, hypothetically, that I was suspended on StackOverflow on May 25 '18, does that exclude me from being a possible nominee in this election?  I'm not yet sure if I am interested in being a candidate, I'm just curious how this rule works.

Comment: @mickmackusa: It would. The counting is a year from the _end_ of the suspension and I check when people nominate themselves. The primary reason is that a year of good behavior avoids the controversy of someone just coming off of a suspension.

Comment: So any suspension on any SE site within 12 months would prohibit someone from being a candidate in this JSE election?

Comment: @mickmackusa: Yes and that goes for any election on the network. And if someone were suspended for a year, it would take a grand total of two years (one for  the actual suspension and another for the rehabilitation period) be be able to run.

Comment: Surprised nobody has nominated themselves.

Comment: @Lodder: It's still too soon yet. ;-) We'll see what happens after May 13.

Comment: @JonEricson - Oh, I could have sworn it said "March" when I first saw the post :)

Comment: ... @Lodder there was a strong probability of me raising my hand because I enjoy moderation and I visit multiple times daily, but my conduct on Stackoverflow excludes me for a couple of months after the scheduled election date.

Comment: Hmm that really is a shame cause you would 100% get my vote. Maybe an small exception can be made